# Separate permissions for form vs list

Tags: permissions

I created a form that I need everyone to access and submit items, but I don't want everyone to have access to view the list that the form is tied to. Can I have separate permissions for the form vs. the list?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I learned from another resource that having separate permissions for the form and the list it's tied to is not possible. The solution is to create a new default view restricting the information that is displayed on the list. And then create a private view revealing all the information that the appropriate people need to see.